# Different lowess curves in plot and qplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I am comparing two graphs with a non-parametric lo(w)ess curve superimposed in each case. The problem is  that the curves look very different, despite the fact that their arguments, such as span, are identical.

[image]

[image]

```
y<-rnorm(100)
x<-rgamma(100,2,2)
qplot(x,y)+stat_smooth(span=2/3,se=F)+theme_bw()
plot(x,y)
lines(lowess(y~x))
```

There seems to be a lot more curvatute in the graph generated by `qplot()`. As you know detecting curvature is very important in the diagnostics of regression analysis and I fear that If I am to use ggplot2, I would reach erroneous conclusions.

Could you please tell me how I could produce the same curve in ggplot2?

Thank you

Comment: You are using two different fitting functions: a `loess` line (using `qplot`) and a `lowess` (using `lines`).

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Both lowess and loess refer to the same smoothing function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression ,no? If not  , is there an equivalent function in ggplot2?

Comment: No they don't. Read more carefully! And see [**here**](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2003-September/002337.html).

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Wow, you are very right. The loess curve fits quadratic local regression by default, hence the curvature. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, you can use `loess(..., degree=1)`. This produces a very similar, but not quite identical result to `lowess(...)`

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducibility
y<-rnorm(100)
x<-rgamma(100,2,2)
plot(x,y)
points(x,loess(y~x,data.frame(x,y),degree=1)$fitted,pch=20,col="red")
lines(lowess(y~x))
```

[image]

With `ggplot`

```
qplot(x,y)+stat_smooth(se=F,degree=1)+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_point(data=as.data.frame(lowess(y~x)),aes(x,y),col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a new `stat` function for use with `ggplot2` that uses `lowess()`: https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/blob/master/R/stat-plsmo.r.  You need to load the `proto` package for this to work.  I like using `lowess` because it is fast for any sample size and allows outlier detection to be turned off for binary Y.  But it doesn't provide confidence bands.